# Connecting NestJS application running on localhost to a bitnami/mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, nestjs

I am trying to connect to bitnami/mongodb using a NestJS application running on localhost, but the application does not connect the way I know. How to solve this problem?

docker-compose file:

```
version: "2"
services:
  mongodb-primary:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mongodb:5.0
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password123
      - MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME=localhost
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE=primary
      - MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password123
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY=replicasetkey123
    volumes:
      - "mongodb_master_data:/bitnami/mongodb"
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

  mongodb-secondary:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mongodb:5.0
    depends_on:
      - mongodb-primary
    environment:
      - MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME=mongodb-secondary
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE=secondary
      - MONGODB_INITIAL_PRIMARY_HOST=mongodb-primary
      - MONGODB_INITIAL_PRIMARY_ROOT_PASSWORD=password123
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY=replicasetkey123

  mongodb-arbiter:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mongodb:5.0
    depends_on:
      - mongodb-primary
    environment:
      - MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME=mongodb-arbiter
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE=arbiter
      - MONGODB_INITIAL_PRIMARY_HOST=mongodb-primary
      - MONGODB_INITIAL_PRIMARY_ROOT_PASSWORD=password123
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY=replicasetkey123

volumes:
  mongodb_master_data:
    driver: local
```

the configuration in the root module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: '.env',
      isGlobal: true,
    }),

    MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://root:password123@localhost:27017/'),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: What is the specific problem you're running into?  Is there an error message you're getting?  When you say the NextJS process is running "on localhost", is it on the same physical machine as the MongoDB containers, in its own container with its own isolated localhost, or somewhere else?

Comment: The application works on the local device "localhost". The database in the container I want to connect them using port mapping (by the external port) and the error is:
 ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database.

Comment: can you try to use the name of the db container instead of localhost?
for example: mongodb://root:password123@mongodb-primary:27017/

Comment: But I am working outside the container, the host on the device is not within the deocker environment,and it does not work either. I have not been able to solve the problem yet with bitnami. I use mongo image normally using environment variables to connect, but with bitnami mongo, I do not know how to connect to it from outside the container!